# What is wrong with this code? Is something wrong with the %s?

Tags: python

```
Name = input("What is your Name?")
Hobby = input("What is your Hobby
Color = input("What is your favorite Color?")

print ("Ah, so your Name is %s, your Hobby is %s, ") \
("and your favorite Color is %s. " % (Name, Hobby, Color)
```

Hi Guys!
I have started coding a few days ago and was going to do a query code.

Now... my problem is that this code doesn't work. I have tested a few things why it doesn't but I can't find the error.

When I run it an error message appears :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/master/Documents/Untitled3.py", line 6, in <module>
    ("and your favorite Color is %s.") (Name,Hobby,Color)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: your code has a typo. Please fix it.

Comment: but where? i can't find it

Comment: The typo Jean-Francois probably refers to is at the end of line 2. You forgot ?")

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the full working code :
   the format you've used is incorrect for printing .

```
Name = input("What is your Name?")
Hobby = input("What is your Hobby")
Color = input("What is your favorite Color?")

print ("Ah, so your Name is %s, your Hobby is %s,and your favorite Color is %s. " % (Name, Hobby, Color))
```

Alternatively I will suggest you to use `string.format` it is much easier to use atleast i think so.

```
print ("Ah, so your Name is {0}, your Hobby is {1},and your favorite Color is {2} .".format(Name, Hobby, Color))
```

**Output :**

```
What is your Name?toheed
What is your Hobbycricket
What is your favorite Color?blue
Ah, so your Name is toheed, your Hobby is cricket,and your favorite Color is blue.
```

Comment: so {0} is the same as %s?

Comment: Yes it is exactly same

Comment: ("foo: %s" % str_value) is equivalent to ("foo: {0}".format(str_value))

Comment: Yes. That wasnt it but that doesnt matter - i have another question: Name = input("What is your name?")
Hobby = input("What is your Hobby?")
Color = input("What is your favorite Color?")

print("Ah, so your Name is %s, your Hobby is %s, "
    "and your favorite Color is %s. " % (Name, Hobby, Color))

print("How old are you?")
input("Type your age here:")                                                          I want to calculate the date of birth by their age and the date right now(2018). I need to calculate 2018 - the age of the person. How do I do that? I just cant get it right lol.

Comment: @Constantin you can always put it ask a new question . we can help you with that as well :)

Comment: @toheedNiaz I just did... just needed to wait 1 1/2 for another question

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the result of the print statement:

```
result_of_print = print("Ah, so your Name is %s, your Hobby is %s, ")
result_of_print("and your favorite Color is %s. " % (Name, Hobby, Color))
```

but `result_of_print` is `None`.

Correct the parentheses:

```
print("Ah, so your Name is %s, your Hobby is %s, "
    "and your favorite Color is %s. " % (Name, Hobby, Color))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem it is you are closing the pirnt function

> print ("Ah, so your Name is %s, your Hobby is %s, ")(just here) \ ("and your favorite Color is %s. " % (Name, Hobby, Color)

You can do `print ("Ah, so your Name is %s, your Hobby is %s, "+
"and your favorite Color is %s. " % (Name, Hobby, Color))`